# How do I fetch images of the internet in FXRuby?

Tags: ruby, fxruby

so let me preface this with the fact that I am a beginner at ruby and FXruby. I would like to know how I can fetch images by using a URL. This is the code I used when getting them off my desktop:

```
require 'rubygems'

require 'fox16'

include Fox


class Image_Viewer <FXMainWindow
  def initialize(app)
    super(app, "Image Viewer", :opts => DECOR_ALL, :width => 500, :height => 450) 
    @pic = File.open("/Users/AdamAshwal/Desktop/image.jpg", "rb")
    @pic2 = FXJPGImage.new(app, @pic.read)
    FXImageFrame.new(self, @pic2)

end 
  def create
    super
    self.show(PLACEMENT_SCREEN)
end

end


app = FXApp.new
mainwin = Image_Viewer.new(app)

app.create
app.run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be

```
require 'open-uri'
```

and not

```
require 'open-url'
```

Comment: Ya, cool thanks. Then can I just copy and paste in any url? Like: @pic = File.open("http://www.dream-worlds.net/forum/uploads/100/platypus.jpg", "rb")

Comment: For one thing, you need to use open() instead of File.open(), as Resse Moore showed in his example. For another thing, the string you listed ("dream-worlds.net...") is not a URL. For yet another thing, even if I make it a URL I can't fetch that image over the 'net anyways (permission denied).

Answer (score 0):

Just do a:

```
require 'open-url'
```

then

```
@pic = open("http://website.com/imgs/image.png")
```

Then treat it as you would treat any other `File`

Comment: It then says "No file to load",

Comment: Have you verified the the image exists at the URL you specified?

Comment: Well I went on to google images and just found a random image and used that URL if thats what you mean